# How to raise issue for jersey in java.net/jira?

Tags: jersey

I would like to raise an issue against jersey in java.net/jira:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY

But I can't see any way to register or create an issue anonymously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues can be opened for Jersey on the [issues tab](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues) of their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jersey/jersey).

Comment: The links are broken. Says *java.net site has closed*

Comment: Thanks @VisruthCV I've edited the answer to point to where Jersey currently tracks issues.